# AJAX variables javascript to php does not work

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Hello guys I don't understand what is the problem with my code. I'll be really grateful if someone helps me. The values of the parameters in PHP never change.

The form

```
<form id= 'id' method="post" ><input type='text' value='<?php echo $var1; ?>' name='<?php echo $var3; ?>'> <input type='text' value='<?php echo $var2; ?>' name='<?php echo $var3; ?>'><input type='submit' value='Update' onclick = 'update("<?php echo $var1 ?>", "<?php echo $var2 ?>", "<?php echo $var3 ?>"); '><br></form>
```

The JavaScript

```
function update(var1, var2, var3){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'file.php',
        data: {
            'var1' : var1,
            'var2' : var2,
            'var3' : var3
        },

    });   
}
```

And the PHP :

```
$var1 =  '';
if(isset($_POST['var1']))
    $var1 = $_POST['va1'];

$var2 = '';
if(isset($_POST['var2']))
    $var2 = $_POST['var2'];

$var3 =  '';
if(isset($_POST['var3']))
    $var3 = $_POST['var3'];
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you add the actual problem to your question or what you expect to happen?

Comment: You need to output your variables in some way if you want them to be returned to your ajax request. Also, your ternaries already sets your variables to the correct values. The `if`'s are totally redundant.

Comment: Is the `url` parameter pointing at a proper/existing path? What do you see in your JS console?

Comment: `$var1 = !empty($_POST['var1']) ? $_POST['var1'] : '';` you dont have to do this, directly inside the `if` statement you can do this way
`if(isset($_POST['var1']) && !empty($_POST['var1'])) { $var1 = $_POST['var1']; }`

Comment: You did not actually say what the problem is, but I am guessing that your AJAX is not POSTing the data you expect.  That's because you are setting variables like `$var1` in PHP, and trying to access them as `var1` in Javascript.  That's won't work - there is no connection between JS variables on the client and PHP variables on the server.  Try (in your JS) `'var1': <?php echo $var1; ?>` ... etc.

Comment: @Kyrre yes I just put this name for the example.

Comment: I use a form and onclick method to past the to the javaScript I will edit my post to show the form

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript does this:

> ```
> success: function( data ) {
>     console.log( data );
> }
> ```

So whatever the output of the PHP script is, it will be logged to the Console in your browser's developer tools.

---

Your PHP, does this:

> ```
> $var1 = !empty($_POST['var1']) ? $_POST['var1'] : '';
> if(isset($_POST['var1']))
>     $var1 = $_POST['va1'];
> ```

This is redundant, because you are basically doing the same thing twice:

```
$var1 = !empty($_POST['var1']) ? $_POST['var1'] : '';
```

… would be sufficient.

---

However, that is **all** the PHP does.

It sets the variables and then outputs nothing.

Consequently, when you log `data` in the JS, nothing is output.

You need to change the PHP so it does something with the variables if you want anything useful to happen.

---

You also said:

> ```
> <input type='text' value='<?php echo $var1; ?>'
> ```

Which suggests you might expect setting the variables to change the values in the inputs.

This won't happen.

1. You run a program and got some output (an HTML document).
2. You ran another program and didn't get any output

They are **different** programs (or possibly they are the same program run at different times).

The second program has no influence on the output of the first program.

Consider this by way of comparison:

1. Write a document in Microsoft Word
2. Print it
3. Write another document in Microsoft Word
4. Look at the paper

What you printed on the paper has changed just because you wrote another document.

---

If you want to change the values of the inputs then you need to send the data to the browser and change them with JavaScript.

First, output the data in a sensible format:

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
echo json_encode({
    var1 => $var1,
    var2 => $var2,
    var3 => $var3,
});
```

Then write the JS to do something with that data:

```
    success: function( data ) {
        // This sets the value of the first input element in the document by way of example. Extrapolate from there to set the things you actually care about
        jQuery("input").val(data.var1);
    }
```

Comment: Is there a possibility AJAX to work without a success part because I am using exactly the same and it is working the only difference is that I have only one var in the other method

Answer (score -1):

If there is a `$_POST` you should check with isset, that should be enough. No need for the `!empty`

```
$var1 = isset($_POST['var1']) ? $_POST['var1'] : "";
```

Comment: This should be a comment, since it doesn't actually change the outcome of the script by much. We don't even know if the OP's ajax is posting to the correct URL, or if there are any code that actually outputs the variables.